# Serving express files from base directory

Tags: express

How do would I serve static files from my base directory? Would it just be a `/` or would I have to include the name of the base directory, which in this case would be `Scanning`

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '/')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close, just a few adjustments!

```js
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/Scanning`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use or construct the actual full path to the base directory.  You don't show your actual directory structure and where the desired directory is relative to the directory that your code is running from.

If you wanted `express.static()` to serve from the `Scanning` directory which is a sub-directory of the directory you code is located in, you would do this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Scanning')));
```

Or, if `Scanning` is a sibling of `__dirname`, then it would be this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../Scanning')));
```

You should never be serving files with `express.static()` directly from `__dirname` because that would allow your server to serve up your actual source files (and sometimes things like credentials).

Comment: But what if Scanning is my directory? I just need to know this for testing purposes...

Comment: @KirtM9 - Then, you would do `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`, but I explained that that is dangerous.  Simply move your public resources to a different directory and point at that instead.  You should not be using `express.static()` pointed at your source code directory.

Comment: @KirtM9 - Did this answer your question?